# How to rename multiple files in a directory leaving the extension in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I need to rename files in a directory taking out a string of characters that is different with each file but starts the same way. I know how to strip characters from the filename, but how do I preserve the extension? I know it's a variation of a common question but I can't find a answer that fits my exact need.

```
Redshirts_ep6_dSBHpCsvQ3BfQ7-NNIjXYO4pnHpNMvu7bfvURLF3BSzB_3YOOrBBoNnICTR-hg.mp3
-> Redshirts.mp3
PathsNotTaken_ep6_XWixFER4PJyeozVfcxT96UajpnVI7cRMRhAU4Aj9-rpeacnBleuGY9zCPDe0aQ.mp3
-> PathsNotTaken.mp3
```

Comment: So you want to remove the first `_` and everything after it, up until the first `.`?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: `mv $file ${file/_*./.}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linux command `rename` is super helpful here. It can use regex to perform the renaming.

This can probably rewritten a bit, but it appears do to the job here:

```
rename -n 's/(^[^_]*)_.*/$1.mp3/' *.mp3
```

Just remove that `-n` flag to run for for real. Leaving it on is just a test.

This regex says:

Characters at the start of the line `^` that don't contain an underscore `[^_]` repeated any number of times `*` are captured into a capture group `(^[^_]*)` if they are followed by an underscore and any number of any other characters `_.*`. These are then rewritten by using that first capture group `$1` followed by `.mp3`

Comment: Why not simply `rename 's/_.*/.mp3/' *.mp3` ?

Comment: It's worth noting that this requires the Perl implementation of `rename` as found in Debian based distros. Other distros default to the util-linux `rename` tool where this does not work.